# self referential join using linq

Tags: c#, linq

My database has a students table:

```
StudentID int PK
StudentName varchar
FamilyID int (Nullable)
```

If a student has siblings in the database, they will share a familyID. If a student has no siblings, familyID should be null.

Using Linq, given a StudentID, how do a return a list containing a student and all his siblings (if any)?

Answer (score 3):

A `join` with an `into` should do the trick.

```
var query = from s in students
            join s2 in students.Where(x => x.StudentId != s.StudentId) on s.FamilyId equals s2.FamilyId into siblings
            select new
            {
              Student = s,
              Siblings = siblings,
            };
```

You can add a `query.FirstOrDefault(x => s.StudentId == yourStudentId)` in order to get a specific StudentId

Comment: This doesn't compile. I get "the name 's' doesn't exist in the current context".

Comment: The error refers to the s in the following clause: (x => x.StudentID != s.StudentID)

Answer (score 2):

Using a LinQ method chain, this will return a list of only the siblings:

```
var siblings = students.Where(s => s.FamilyId == students.Single(st => st.StudentId == id).FamilyId).ToList();
```

or in 2 steps so you could provide checks on the student-instance:

```
var student = students.Single(st => st.Id == id);
var siblings = students.Where(s => s.FamilyId == student.FamilyId).ToList();
```

Comment: Why split them, the OP asked for 'a list containing a student and all his siblings (if any)?'.  Just omit the 's.StudentId != id' clause from the first code should give that. Yes/No?

Comment: You're absolutely right! I read it wrong, I thought he only wanted the siblings.. I updated my answer, thanks again! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
List<Student> lstStd = new List<Student>();

var student = (from s in students 
where s.studentid = studentid
select s).FirstOrDefault();
lstStd.Add(student);    

if(student!=null)
{
     if( student.FamilyId !=null)
         {
                  lstStd.AddRange( (from s in students
                  where s.FamilyId == student.Familyid
                      && s.studentid != student.studentid
                  select s).ToList<Student>());
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var sid = 123;
  var query = from s in Students
              where (from s2 in Students where s2.Id == sid select s2.FamilyId).FirstOrDefault() == s.FamilyId
              && s.FamilyId != null
              select s;
```

if i understand your question correctly. you are looking for the family members of a specified student id.  this answer is based on the assumption that you are only looking for one family at a time, and not a list of all families.